# Account restrictions when accessing UNC path

Tags: windows, permissions, unc

I have a number of servers on the network and occasionally I need to connect to all of them to copy files across, or just make changes.

When I use Windows Explorer and enter a path like `\\server01\c$\some\directory\`, I get a Network Error:

[image: network error]

This happens when I haven't previously (in the current session) connected to the drive specified in the path.  So in the above example, if I was to first try `\\server01\c$`, I will get a security popup like so:

[image: security popup]

I can then enter my details, and then re-navigate to the original path and I can see it just fine.

My question is, can I script this process?  Ideally I want to have a text file or similar of all the server names, then run a script which will do the login phase for all of the servers.  Then I am free to do what I need without repeatedly logging in.  I am not sure what to look for when searching for solutions to this online since the keywords are quite generic.

*I have used online images for the screenshots, hence the difference in window style...*

Comment: "Remember my credentials" will put them into Windows' Credential Manager.  You can also manually add credentials to the Credential Manager, so perhaps try that?

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding the server name to the Credentials Manager (with and without the `c$` bit) but I still get the Security popup. Also I don't get the 'remember your credentials' option so I'm wondering if group policy is blocking password storing...